# Zipar pasta excetuando um subdiretório

Tags: linux, arquivo-zip

Para *zipar* uma pasta no *Linux* uso o comando abaixo.

```
zip -r arquivoZipado.zip pastaSerZipada/
```

Como posso *zipar*, excetuando, um subdiretório de *pastaSerZipada*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *zip* possui a *flag* `-x` ou `--exclude`, que permite definir máscaras de nomes de arquivos e diretórios a serem ignorados durante a operação.

Assim, para ignorar todo o subdiretório `subdir-fora-do-zip` na compactação da seguinte estrutura de arquivos...

```
para-zipar/
  ├─ arquivo-no-zip
  ├─ subdir-fora-do-zip/
  │    └─ arquivo-fora-do-zip
  └─ subdir-no-zip
       └─ arquivo-no-zip
```

...execute:

```
zip -r zipado.zip para-zipar -x '*subdir-fora-do-zip*'
```

> **Obs.:** Os asteriscos são importantes para garantir que o diretório em questão seja ignorado independentemente do nível de recursão em que se encontrar.

Testando o arquivo compactado, pode-se verificar o sucesso do uso da *flag* `-x`:

> ```
> $ unzip -t zipado.zip 
> Archive:  zipado.zip
>     testing: para-zipar/              OK
>     testing: para-zipar/arquivo-no-zip   OK
>     testing: para-zipar/subdir-no-zip/   OK
>     testing: para-zipar/subdir-no-zip/arquivo-no-zip   OK
> No errors detected in compressed data of zipado.zip.
> ```